# How to suspend kotlin coroutine until notified

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to suspend a Kotlin coroutine until a method is called from outside, just like the old Java `object.wait()` and `object.notify()` methods. How do I do that?

Here: [Correctly implementing wait and notify in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44589669) is an answer how to implement this with Kotlin threads (blocking). And here: [Suspend coroutine until condition is true](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53906195) is an answer how to do this with `CompleteableDeferreds` but I do not want to have to create a new instance of `CompleteableDeferred` every time.

I am doing this currently:

```kotlin
    var nextIndex = 0

    fun handleNext(): Boolean {
        if (nextIndex < apps.size) {
            //Do the actual work on apps[nextIndex]
            nextIndex++
        }
        //only execute again if nextIndex is a valid index
        return nextIndex < apps.size
    }

    handleNext()

    // The returned function will be called multiple times, which I would like to replace with something like notify()
    return ::handleNext
```

[Source](https://gitlab.com/SuperFreezZ/SuperFreezZ/blob/master/src/superfreeze/tool/android/backend/Freezer.kt#L69)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Channels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/channels.html) can be used for this (though they are more general):

> When capacity is 0 – it creates RendezvousChannel. This channel does not have any buffer at all. An element is transferred from sender to receiver only when send and receive invocations meet in time (rendezvous), so send suspends until another coroutine invokes receive and receive suspends until another coroutine invokes send.

So create

```
val channel = Channel<Unit>(0)
```

And use [`channel.receive()`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-receive-channel/receive.html) for  `object.wait()`, and [`channel.offer(Unit)`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-send-channel/offer.html) for `object.notify()` (or `send` if you want to wait until the other coroutine `receive`s).

For `notifyAll`, you can use [`BroadcastChannel`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.channels/-broadcast-channel/index.html) instead.

You can of course easily encapsulate it:

```
inline class Waiter(private val channel: Channel<Unit> = Channel<Unit>(0)) {

    suspend fun doWait() { channel.receive() }
    fun doNotify() { channel.offer(Unit) }
}
```

Comment: The downside: It's not 100% what channels are supposed for, which might make the code more difficult to read. But as there seems not to be any better solution I'll accept it if there is no other answer in the next time.

Comment: It's some extra code and it's no "standard" class but I still like it as the best possible solution.

Comment: For your suggested edit: `internal` won't affect performance (or if it does, I'd be very surprised), and I don't see a reason to pass the channel in the constructor.

Comment: Especially because calling it with a channel of non-zero capacity breaks the intended use.

Comment: I meant inline :-( and this requires using the primary constructor.

Comment: Ok, I approved the edit. But to be honest, the overhead should be very small even without it.

Comment: Hey, how would the implementation with a BroadcastChannel look like? With a BroadcastChannel we don't have a receive operation and also there is no such thing like a rendezvous BroadcastChannel. Would we have to open a new subscription for every doWait()?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov would this work with multiple coroutines suspended on doWait() ?

Comment: @kr15hna Yes, I believe. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/channels.html#fan-out.

Comment: @MaxGierlachowski Missed this earlier, sorry. Yes, you are right, no rendevouz BroadcastChannel is a problem. So this approach may not work...

Answer (score 13):

It is possible to use the basic `suspendCoroutine{..}` function for that, e.g.

```
class SuspendWait() {
  private lateinit var myCont: Continuation<Unit>
  suspend fun sleepAndWait() = suspendCoroutine<Unit>{ cont ->
    myCont = cont
  }

  fun resume() {
    val cont = myCont
    myCont = null
    cont.resume(Unit)
  }
}
```

It is clear, the code have issues, e.g. `myCont` field is not synchonized, it is expected that `sleepAndWait` is called before the `resume` and so on, hope the idea is clear now.

There is another solution with the `Mutex` class from the kotlinx.coroutines library.

```
class SuspendWait2 {
  private val mutex = Mutex(locaked = true)
  suspend fun sleepAndWait() = mutex.withLock{}
  fun resume() {
    mutex.unlock()
  }
}
```

Comment: With these solutions I will need to create a new object for each "sleep-and-notify-cycle" again. This will increase the boilerplate code. Actually it's the same problem as with CompleteableDeferreds (see my question) (correct my if I am wrong).

Comment: @Nemo with mutex you can reuse object, if you want to invoke it many times check channels

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using a `CompletableJob` for that.

My use case:

```
suspend fun onLoad() {
    var job1: CompletableJob? = Job()
    var job2: CompletableJob? = Job()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        someList.collect {
            doSomething(it)
            job1?.complete()
        }
    }

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        otherList.collect {
            doSomethingElse(it)
            job2?.complete()
        }
    }

    joinAll(job1!!, job2!!) // suspends until both jobs are done

    job1 = null
    job2 = null

    // Do something one time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Mutex & Shared Flow it is possible. I made an example where only one task with the same id is executing at a time. Ids are stored in the set. If id in the set, then task with this id is executing.

```
private class SharedResourceCoroutinesSync {

    private val ids: MutableSet<String> = mutableSetOf()

    // passes only one coroutine at a time
    private val mutex = Mutex()
    // Shared flow gives all waiters its values
    private val signal = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(0,1,BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)

    // only one task with the same id can be executed at a time
    suspend fun submitTaskById(
        id: String,
        task: suspend ()->Unit
    ): Job = coroutineScope {

        while (true){

            // analogue of entering java synchronized block
            mutex.lock() // only one coroutine at once can pass, others suspends

            if (id !in ids){ // check if this id is busy

                ids += id // if not busy then make it busy

                // analogue of leaving java synchronized block
                mutex.unlock() // allow other coroutines to check

                break // go out from loop to do task
            }

            // if this id is busy, we need to wait, and need to be notified

            // subscribe on shared flow events, then unlock mutex
            // subscribe BEFORE unlock, so other coroutines can't push notifyAll events before we can receive them
            signal.onSubscription {
                // analogue of leaving java synchronized block
                mutex.unlock()
            }
                .take(1)
                .collect() // analogue of java blocking wait()
        }

        // returns Job
        launch {
            task() // executes some task
            mutex.withLock { // analogue of java synchronized block
                ids -= id // release this id
                signal.emit(Unit) // analogue of java notifyAll()
            }
        }
    }
}
```